# Java ArrayList add class object to list if object name is not already in the list?

Tags: java, class, arraylist, java.util.scanner, contains

I have looked through other questions but cant seem to find the answer I am looking for.

I am having trouble figuring out how to create a loop that adds a class object to an `ArrayList` only if it its name is not used in the list already.

This is the class I have.

```
package myPackage;

public class Cube {
    private int length;
    private String name;

    public Cube(int initLength, String initName) {
        this.length = initLength;
        this.name = initName;
    }
```

I would like to create new cubes and add them to a list. Here is the code I am trying to do this with.

In the while loop I can't figure out how to determine if the name has been used or not

```
package myPackage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PartFive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Cube> cubelist = new ArrayList<>();
        Cube oshea = new Cube (13, "oshea");
        Cube mike = new Cube (7, "tony");
        cubelist.add(oshea);
        cubelist.add(mike);

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("enter cube name (blank quits): ");
            String name = reader.nextLine();
            if (name.equals("")){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("enter side length: ");
            int length = Integer.valueOf(reader.nextLine());

            Cube newcube = new Cube(length, name);
            if(cubelist.contains(newcube.name)) {
                // dont add to list
            }
            else {
                cubelist.add(newcube);
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        System.out.println(cubelist);
    }
}
```

Any constructive criticisms and suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
if(cubelist.contains(newcube.name)) {
  dont add to list
}
else {
  cubelist.add(newcube);
}
```

with

```
boolean found = false;
for(Cube cube: cubelist){
    if(cube.getName().equals(name)) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!found) {
    cubelist.add(newcube);
}
```

The idea is to use a `boolean` variable to track if a cube with the same name as that of the input `name` already exists in the list. For this, iterate `cubelist` and if a cube with the same name as that of the input `name` is found, change the state of the `boolean` variable and `break` the loop. If the state of the `boolean` variable does not change throughout the loop, add the cube to the list.

Answer (score 2):

From the code in your question:

```java
if(cubelist.contains(newcube.name)) {
    // don't add to list
}
else {
    cubelist.add(newcube);
}
```

Method [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) in class `java.utilArrayList` is the way to go but you need to be aware that method `contains` [eventually] calls method [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) of its element type. In your case, the element type is `Cube`. Therefore you need to add a `equals` method to class `Cube`. I don't know what determines whether two `Cube` objects are equal, but I'll guess, according to your question, that they are equal if they have the same `name`, even when they have different `length`s. I will further assume that `name` cannot be null. Based on those assumptions, here is a `equals` method. You should add this method to class `Cube`.

```java
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    boolean areEqual = false;
    if (this == obj) {
        areEqual = true;
    }
    else {
        if (obj instanceof Cube) {
            Cube other = (Cube) obj;
            areEqual = name.equals(other.name);
        }
    }
    return areEqual;
}
```

Now, in method `main` of class `PartFive` you can use the following `if` to add a `Cube` to the list.

```java
if (!cubelist.contains(newcube)) {
    cubelist.add(newcube);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for duplicate names in the *cubelist* array using lambda expressions (for better readability):

```
 boolean isNameAlreadyExisting = cubelist.stream()
                .anyMatch(cube -> cube.getName().equals(newcube.getName())); // this is returning true if any of the cubelist element's name is equal with the newcube's name, meaning that the name is already existing in the cubelist 

 if (!isNameAlreadyExisting) {
   cubelist.add(newcube);
 }
```

One thing that you should do is to remove the *while(true)* instruction which causes an infinite loop.
Another suggestion is to display the name of objects contained by *cubelist*, to see that indeed the names are not duplicated:

```
cubelist.stream()
        .map(Cube::getName)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```